# Why my program keep asking values continuously if I add this line

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to increase the value of `s` by the call by reference but when I add `*s=*s+5;` my code is going to a loop of continuously getting values

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node* push(node *head,int newdata,int *s)
{
    node *newnode,*temp;
    newnode=new node;
    newnode->data=newdata;
    if(head==0) head=temp=newnode;

    else
    {
        newnode->next=head;
        head=newnode;
    }
    *s=*s+5;             //this line
    return head;
}
void print(node *head,int s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<head->data;
        head=head->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *head=0;
    int s,a;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
    cin>>a;
    head=push(head,a,&s);
    }
    print(head,s);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What were you exactly expecting? you are increasing `s` by 5 while `i` by 1. And when `s` overflows you have undefined behavior.

Comment: You would attract more readers if you formatted your code consistently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an infinite loop because `i < s` is always true since you increase `s` by 5 on every `push` function call. Here's your loop:

```
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++){
```

After every iteration it checks whether `i < s`. But you are increasing `s` by 5 in the function `push()`:

```
*s=*s+5;             //this line
```

Thus, `i` is always less than `s` and the loop keeps on looping. Think of this like, `i` is trying to catch `s` but everytime `i` takes a step, `s` takes 5 steps and runs away. Thus, i is never able to catch `s` and hence your loop never finishes.

If you keep on looping some day `s` will become so huge that it will not be able to increase any more and it will overflow. Thus you will enter the realm of undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour means that no one knows *exactly* what will happen. Anything can happen, but most likely your program will crash. But it can do other bad things, so you should quickly fix this by not changing `s` while the loop is looping :)